# How to reload a tableview only once at the end of a parse query?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Essentially, I have built a `tableviewcontroller` with a `PFQuery` to load information for each individual cell and store it in a array. There are two calls to parse, one to store usernames into an array, and another one to check if the current user is "following" them.

```
var query = PFUser.query()

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)   // users is an array declared globally

        for object in objects {
                var user:PFUser = object as PFUser
                var isFollowing:Bool
                if user.username != PFUser.currentUser().username {
                        self.users.append(user.username)
                        isFollowing = false
                        var query = PFQuery(className:"followers")
                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser().username)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo:user.username)
                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                                (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {
                                        for object in objects {
                                                isFollowing = true
                                        }

                                        self.following.append(isFollowing)
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                                } else {
                                        // Log details of the failure
                                        println(error)
                                }
                        }

                }
        }
}
```

If I call `reloadData()` at another place, the table will not display correctly. This makes my table loading inefficient..since the table reloads with every check for the "isfollowing" variable. How would I make it reload only once? After all the "isfollowing" variable have been appended? Can you please outline the solution step by step so I can get a general sense of direction and what to learn.

EDIT2:

In the code above I query to check which users the currentUser is following. If they are following them, I append "true" to the array "following". The code below is what I'm doing to checkmark the tableviewcells to show that they are following other users. With my original code, all the cells become checkmarked after scrolling up and down a couple of times, why?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    if following.count > indexPath.row {

        if following[indexPath.row] == true {

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

        }

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = users[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

EDIT: Wrong code posted originally.

Comment: Dispatch `reloadData` to the main thread and make sure that `userNewNames` and `userImagesFiles` are accessed in a thread-safe way.

Comment: I posted the wrong code initially. Please take a quick look again! Thanks

Comment: To solve the problem, do I save the result of the entire query with coreData, then with NSNotificationCenter, call reloadData() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findObjects` to call synchronously and put it in our own queue may helps.

```
// queue is declared as an instance property
let queue = dispatch_queue_create(nil, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

var query = PFUser.query()

dispatch_async(queue) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)   // users is an array declared globally
    }

    for user in query.findObjects() as [PFUser] {
        var isFollowing = false

        if user.username != PFUser.currentUser().username {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.users.append(user.username)
            }

            var query = PFQuery(className:"followers")

            query.whereKey("follower", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser().username)
            query.whereKey("following", equalTo:user.username)

            // call findObjects synchronously
            if let objects = query.findObjects() {
                if !objects.isEmpty {
                    isFollowing = true
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.following.append(isFollowing)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // notify table view to reload
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

You can create a UITableViewCell subclass and override its `prepareForReuse` to reset `accessoryType`.

```
class MyTableView: UITableViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        accessoryType = .None
    }
}
```

In your code, you didn't handle the case for `following[indexPath.row] != true`. If you don't want to subclass UITableViewCell, you can also reset the checkmark there.

Comment: Thanks Swipesight. Just googled "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())" and was alitte confused. Does it run append() asynchronously in background inside the query block. Then calling dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) again runs reloadData() ONLY when the previous dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) has finished? Would it not run reloadData before the query has finished? Thanks for helping a beginner

Comment: Actually your code has made every "isFollowing" true for some reason.. :(

Comment: The tableview now is empty while the activity indicator runs endlessly in the status bar. Again, appreciate the help so far.

Comment: @user3483697 After looking the source code of PFQuery, the block passed to `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` will be executed on the calling thread, so my previous code got a deadlock, check my code again, please.

Comment: It works, but is now slower than the original code. It also does something weird. In my code I put a checkmark on cells that have a "true" value for their corresponding value in the following array. Initially the view loads the checkmarks correctly..but after scrolling down and up, all the cells become checkmarked. I have posted my code for the check marking.

Comment: Because cells are reused, you can override `prepareForReuse` method to reset it. About the performance, can you provide more information?

Comment: I see! Maybe the lag is unavoidable since the table loads 40+ cells and a query for each one? Currently I see a blank tableview for about 10 seconds, then the tableview loads fine with the usernames and the correct checkmark at once.

Comment: can you please show me the starting point on how I could solve the checkmark problem with prepareForUse? Thanks again!!

Comment: About the performance issue, there are some ways to make it looks better. But I think that's a different question, probably not a good place to answer at this post.